# PHP How output string to html

Tags: javascript, php, string

After print php string in js code I get error

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var editorHtml = "<?php echo $editorHtml; ?>";
</script>
```

When the string contains `"` double-quotes, I get Unexpected token ILLEGAL, because the double-quotes close the JS string in the middle.

```
 <script type = "text/javascript">
     var editorHtml = '<?php echo $editorHtml; ?>';
 </script>
```

I try this, but i get similar problem, if the string contains `'` single-quotes.
I need a unuiversal solution for this, when the string contains `'` AND `"` quotes.

Comment: what??? Please be clear. I can't make head or tail out of it

Comment: For example. echo $string; // aaaa"""///'''llfgfgfgTTTRrkk;     How can i pass it to js?

Comment: is your file an `.html` or `.php` file? You can **only use** php in `.php` files!

Comment: what's in `$editorHtml` ?

Comment: My file php, i now it.  I try to pass my string for example its aaaa"""///'''llfgfgfgTTTRrkk; to js, but i get this error Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: `var editorHtml = '<?php echo json_encode($editorHtml); ?>';`

Comment: ^^ encodes strings as well, and escapes in the proper places.

Comment: It doesnt work when i use single scope i get error, adeneo how to use ^, example please

Comment: @styopdev - I just posted an example, it's right there in the comment ?

Comment: var editorHtml = '<?php echo json_encode($editorHtml); ?>'  this example not help

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    var editorHtml = <?php echo str_replace(array(']]>', '<!'), array(']]\x3E', '\x3C!'), json_encode($editorHtml)); ?>;
</script>
```

Sanitizes in all cases properly.

Comment: Its not work, $editorHtml =  Hello world; i get error Unexpected Identifier, code in browser                                          <script type = "text/javascript">
 var editorHtml = ""Hello world"";
</script>

Comment: @styopdev sorry, i forgot to remove the quotes around statement, now it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Look an example:

```
<?php
   $someVar = 1;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var javaScriptVar = "<?php echo $someVar; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: His question isn't very clear. The problem happens when `$someVar` is a string and contains `"` (in your example, since the JS would become `var javaScriptVar = "some stuff with double-quotes: "foo"";`). The variable needs to be properly escaped.

Comment: How escape it? i use stripslashes(), but it doesnt work

Comment: Another answer has already been posted and you've been given an example in the comments to your question. Further reading: [json_encode documentation](http://www.php.net/json_encode).